# loading the image from local server in android

Tags: android

I wrote the following code and it should load an image from memory card in the **ImageView**. I think the following code is correct. I use **PHP Runner** as local server in my android device.But when I launch my program, It can not load the image.Also **PHP Runner** is active.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
WebView webView;
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(88,255,114));
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/image.jpg");
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }
```

Comment: *I think the following code is correct* -> it is not, you should really read that Android basic training.

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if this image is opening in web browser then load in the app. Also you can use [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for image loading to imageview.